# Google Geocode API Longitude and Latitude unavailble for zip 96101

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

[image]I am using google geocode api, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro. For zipcode 96101 , it is returning "No Results Found".

Although it is avialble https://www.google.com/maps?q=96101+zip+code&um=1&ie=UTF-8&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid57W5k- here

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

5-digit postal codes are hard to find in the Geocoding API, sometimes even with country name, because they are surprisingly ambiguous in a worldwide context. See https://issuetracker.google.com/73030863 for more details.

There is a workaround there which is to use Places API Autocomplete with specific parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [components filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering) to search a postal code? When I execute the following request, I get a postal code in the response

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A96101%7Ccountry%3AUS&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Also check if API key is correct and billing is enabled in your project. After migration to Google Maps Platform in July 2018 they are mandatory.

You can also see this result in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D%26options%3Dtrue%26in_country%3DUS%26in_postal_code%3D96101

I hope this helps!

#### Update

There are plenty of similar questions asked in the public issue tracker. For example, this issue:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77308684

The answer from Google is the following:

> Submitting a request specifying only postal code or string '11937+US' is an incomplete and ambiguous address that may lead to unexpected results.
>   Per documentation [1]: In the new geocoder, ambiguous, "incomplete and badly formatted queries", such as misspelled or nonexistent addresses, are prone to produce ZERO_RESULTS.
>
> If your intent is to search postal codes in the USA please use component filters - either using region biasing or country restriction [2]:
>
> Please also take a look at the Geocoding best practices and FAQs:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_queryformat
>
> [1] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/faq#trbl_zero_results
>
> [2] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

Comment: Yes, i have passed the API Key and everything is working fine. Just for 96101 zipcode i am not getting a response from API.  Please see the  screenshot attached above

Comment: Use components filters instead of passing 96101 as an address parameter. This approach should work.

Comment: Thanks for response, just curious to know https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro why 96101 is returning Zero Results and other Zips like 85085, 15001, 34203 etc are returning proper responses

Comment: According to Google the '96101' string in address parameter is considered as incomplete and ambiguous search and may lead to zero results. Have a look at my update and corresponding issue in public issue tracker.