# Google Maps API query with only ZIP code provides incorrect results

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

We use the Google Maps API, and when a user inputs a 5 digit ZIP code, the results are correct the vast majority of the time; it treats the input as a ZIP code and returns results based on that location.

The problem that has come to our attention is that queries for certain ZIP codes (42025 is our prime example) does NOT return the expected results (Benton, KY). The API call actually returns "status":"ZERO_RESULTS". A similar search on maps.google.com will sometimes produce a positive result, but only if Benton, KY consumes a large portion of the viewport already. A workaround is to add the term "zip" in the query string.

My investigation has shown that the failed results appear to be using the 5 digit string as if a street address, which find nothing. A query for "42020" ends up showing some address near Washington D.C., for example.

Has anyone faced this issue? Any suggestions for how to address this?

Comment: Where does your input data come from?  Will it always be a zip code? Have you  thought about using autocomplete from the places library?

Comment: It is not always going to be a zip code, no. This is information visitors to our page will be entering as a free text field. The purpose is to find resources near the location they specify, which can be anywhere in the USA. I do not believe it would be appropriate to use an autocomplete feature in this case.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using a [component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering) in your Geocoder requests in order to obtain postal codes.

Your requests will be rewritten as

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A42025%7Ccountry%3AUS&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A42020%7Ccountry%3AUS&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Both requests return expected results to me. You can also see it in the Geocoder tool:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D%26options%3Dtrue%26in_country%3DUS%26in_postal_code%3D42025

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D%26options%3Dtrue%26in_country%3DUS%26in_postal_code%3D42020

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for those links! I'm sure they will be helpful in my work. 
In this case it is a free text field gathering input from users of our website, where they specify their search criteria. This may be as specific as a full address, or as non-specific as a something like a city name. I think the only way to get this to work properly will be to modify the API call in the case that the query text 'appears' to be a zip code, and apply your suggestion in that situation.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51862745/google-geocode-api-longitude-and-latitude-unavailble-for-zip-96101/52554148#52554148 and https://issuetracker.google.com/73030863

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Only with zip code search.

```
verifyZipCode_google(zipcode) {
  return this.httpClient.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${zipcode}&components=postal_code:${zipcode}&region=us&sensor=true&key=${environment.GOOGLE_API_KEY}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below should work by adding both address and zip code or country inside components

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&components=zipcode:$zipcode&key=$api_key";
```

OR

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&components=country:US&key=$api_key";
```

Reference link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#component-filtering